# Kafka Streams JsonSerde ObjectNode cannot be cast to class

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I'm working on an example by Stepane Mareek regarding KafkaStreams.

Basically, the code takes transactions and calculates the AccountBalance. Unfortunately I get a ClassCastException and i do not understand why or whats happening.

The Exception:

```
Exception in thread "bank-balance-dz-application-8f38e2f1-fc8e-4bb9-bcb7-82958aa39aff-StreamThread-1" org.apache.kafka.streams.errors.StreamsException: A serializer (org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArraySerializer) is not compatible to the actual value type (value type: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.ObjectNode). Change the default Serdes in StreamConfig or provide correct Serdes via method parameters.
at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.StateSerdes.rawValue(StateSerdes.java:204)
at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.MeteredKeyValueStore.lambda$put$3(MeteredKeyValueStore.java:144)
at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.metrics.StreamsMetricsImpl.maybeMeasureLatency(StreamsMetricsImpl.java:836)
at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.MeteredKeyValueStore.put(MeteredKeyValueStore.java:144)
at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.AbstractReadWriteDecorator$KeyValueStoreReadWriteDecorator.put(AbstractReadWriteDecorator.java:100)
at org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.internals.KStreamAggregate$KStreamAggregateProcessor.process(KStreamAggregate.java:108)
at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorNode.lambda$process$2(ProcessorNode.java:142)
at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.metrics.StreamsMetricsImpl.maybeMeasureLatency(StreamsMetricsImpl.java:836)
at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorNode.process(ProcessorNode.java:142)
at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forward(ProcessorContextImpl.java:236)
at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forward(ProcessorContextImpl.java:216)
at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forward(ProcessorContextImpl.java:168)
at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.SourceNode.process(SourceNode.java:96)
at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamTask.lambda$process$1(StreamTask.java:679)
at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.metrics.StreamsMetricsImpl.maybeMeasureLatency(StreamsMetricsImpl.java:836)
at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamTask.process(StreamTask.java:679)
at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.TaskManager.process(TaskManager.java:1033)
at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.runOnce(StreamThread.java:690)
at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.runLoop(StreamThread.java:551)
at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.run(StreamThread.java:510)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: class com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.ObjectNode cannot be cast to class [B (com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.ObjectNode is in unnamed module of loader 'app'; [B is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
    at org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArraySerializer.serialize(ByteArraySerializer.java:19)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.ValueAndTimestampSerializer.serialize(ValueAndTimestampSerializer.java:104)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.ValueAndTimestampSerializer.serialize(ValueAndTimestampSerializer.java:95)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.ValueAndTimestampSerializer.serialize(ValueAndTimestampSerializer.java:27)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.StateSerdes.rawValue(StateSerdes.java:192)
```

[In debug it tries to use a "valueAndTimestampSerializer?"(Picture in Link)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iTDqR.png)

So I try to explain the Code, hopefully my unterstanding ist right.

1. Banktransaction takes the key and value of the topic and try to parse the key to String and the value to JsonNode
2. Then I group the entries by key and aggregate the values. (Do I have to pass the Serdes again? If i don't pass them would they be serialized as String?)
3. I produce the table to the topic "bank-balance-exactly-once" (Do i have to do the ".toStream()"?)

"My" Code:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.JsonNodeFactory;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.ObjectNode;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerConfig;
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Deserializer;
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serde;
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serdes;
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serializer;
import org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonDeserializer;
import org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonSerializer;
import org.apache.kafka.streams.KafkaStreams;
import org.apache.kafka.streams.StreamsBuilder;
import org.apache.kafka.streams.StreamsConfig;
import org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.*;

import java.time.Instant;
import java.util.Properties;

public class BankBalanceStream {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Properties properties = new Properties();

        properties.put(StreamsConfig.APPLICATION_ID_CONFIG, "bank-balance-application");
        properties.put(StreamsConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "localhost:9092");
        properties.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "earliest");

        properties.put(StreamsConfig.PROCESSING_GUARANTEE_CONFIG, "0");
        properties.put(StreamsConfig.PROCESSING_GUARANTEE_CONFIG, StreamsConfig.EXACTLY_ONCE);

        final Serializer<JsonNode> jsonNodeSerializer = new JsonSerializer();
        final Deserializer<JsonNode> jsonNodeDeserializer = new JsonDeserializer();
        final Serde<JsonNode> jsonSerde = Serdes.serdeFrom(jsonNodeSerializer, jsonNodeDeserializer);

        StreamsBuilder builder = new StreamsBuilder();

        KStream<String, JsonNode> bankTransactions = builder.stream("bank-transactions", Consumed.with(Serdes.String(), jsonSerde));
        
        ObjectNode initialBalance = JsonNodeFactory.instance.objectNode();
        initialBalance.put("count", 0);
        initialBalance.put("balance", 0);
        initialBalance.put("time", Instant.ofEpochMilli(0L).toString());

        KTable<String, JsonNode> bankBalance = bankTransactions
                .groupByKey(Grouped.with(Serdes.String(), jsonSerde))
                .aggregate(
                        () -> initialBalance,
                        (key, transaction, balance) -> newBalance(transaction, balance)
                );

        bankBalance.toStream().to("bank-balance-exactly-once", Produced.with(Serdes.String(), jsonSerde));

        KafkaStreams stream = new KafkaStreams(builder.build(), properties);
        stream.cleanUp();
        stream.start();

        System.out.println(stream.toString());

        Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread(stream::close));

    }

    private static JsonNode newBalance(JsonNode transaction, JsonNode balance) {
        ObjectNode newBalance = JsonNodeFactory.instance.objectNode();
        newBalance.put("count", balance.get("count").asInt() + 1);
        newBalance.put("balance", balance.get("balance").asInt() + transaction.get("amount").asInt());

        Long balanceEpoch = Instant.parse(balance.get("time").asText()).toEpochMilli();
        Long transactionEpoch = Instant.parse(transaction.get("time").asText()).toEpochMilli();
        Instant newBalanceInstant = Instant.ofEpochMilli(Math.max(balanceEpoch, transactionEpoch));
        newBalance.put("time", newBalanceInstant.toString());
        return newBalance;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the aggregate-step I had to provide the serdes again.

```
 KTable<String, JsonNode> bankBalance = bankTransactions
            .groupByKey(Grouped.with(Serdes.String(), jsonSerde))
            .aggregate(
                    () -> initialBalance,
                    (key, transaction, balance) -> newBalance(transaction, balance),
                    Named.as("bank-Transaction-Aggregate"),
                    Materialized.with(Serdes.String(), jsonSerde)
            );
```